# Alamofire invalid value around character 0 only on the real device

Tags: swift, alamofire

Node.js

```
router.get('/mp3', function(req, res, next) {

var lists = [

{
    title : "Conversation 01", desc : "xxxx" , url : "xxxx"


},
{
    title : "Conversation 02", desc : "xxxx" , url : "xxxx"

}



];
res.json(lists);
});
```

Swift 2.1

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://myserver/mp3", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
.responseJSON { response in
print(response.request) // original URL request
print(response.response) // URL response
print(response.data) // server data
print(response.result) // result of response serialization

         if let JSON = response.result.value {
             print("JSON: \(JSON)")
         }
     }
```

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around
>   character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around
>   character 0.

The error is returned only on the real device!
No issue for the iOS Simulator!

> The problem is resolved by putting "nil" for the parameters!

Comment: What is `response.data` in the failing case?